# Getting array assignment index out of range while trying to execute the below code.Can someone explain why the below code is wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

```
from array import *
stu=array('i',[])
l=int(input('Enter number of elements in the arrary '))
for i in range(l):
    stu[i]=int(input(f'Enter the {i}th element'))
```

trying to create a user defined array with the above code but getting error:- **array assignment index out of range**.Please explain why the above logic is wrong

Comment: the stu array initialy is empty, it will NOT re-size by itself unless you append to it

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html, python is NOT javascript which automaticaly resizes array if trying to create a new index. In python you HAVE to use `array.append` method

Comment: @Shubham, appreciate your question but please try to keep the title of the question concise and give more information in the body of it. Thanks

Comment: @ disp_name sorry bro ,it was my first time.But thanks for the feedback,will keep that in mind for future refrence